# How to perform arithmetic addition on 2 property of a same object

Tags: javascript

i need to perform arithmetic addition on 2 property of a same object(myTodos)
like
let meetleft =   myTodos.meetings - myTodos.meetDone.

iam expecting some number as result but the actual result is showing as 'Nan'

i tried by first initially declaring a value for meetleft and also use parseInt but still the result is showing as 'NaN'

let meetleft = 0
meetleft = parseInt(myTodos.meetings - myTodos.meetDone)

but this also not worked.

```
let myTodos = {
    day:'monday',
    meetings: 0,
    meetdone: 0,
}
let addMeetings = function(todo,meet=0) {
    todo.meetings = todo.meetings+meet
}

let meetDone = function(todo,meet=0) {
    todo.meetdone = todo.meetdone-meet
}
let restDay = function(todo) {
    todo.meetings=0
    todo.meetDone=0
}
let getSummaryOfDay = function(todo) {
    let meetleft =   todo.meetings + todo.meetDone
    console.log(meetleft)
}
addMeetings(myTodos,4)
addMeetings(myTodos,2)
meetDone(myTodos,5)
getSummaryOfDay(myTodos)
```

from the above code iam expecting the result as 1 but the actual result is NaN

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? Then you can also inspect the content of all variables.

Comment: Sometimes you spell "meetdone" as "meetDone"

Comment: You have a typo in your code `let meetleft =   todo.meetings + todo.meetDone` it should be `let meetleft =   todo.meetings + todo.meetdone` ***meetdone*** and not with _"D"_

Comment: yes, the value of myTodos.meeting=6 and myTodos.meetdone= -5  but after performing myTodos.meeting + myTodos.meetdone the result is coming as Nan instead of 1.

Comment: oh iam sorry guys now it is worked i didn't see that typo mistake

Comment: this was my first question on stackoverflow and thank you everyone for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to `meetdone` and `meetDone` property. Object properties are case sensitive.

Here is the working example:

```
let myTodos = {
    day:'monday',
    meetings: 0,
    meetdone: 0,
}
let addMeetings = function(todo,meet=0) {
    todo.meetings = todo.meetings+meet
}

let meetDone = function(todo,meet=0) {
    todo.meetdone = todo.meetdone-meet
}
let restDay = function(todo) {
    todo.meetings=0
    todo.meetdone=0
}
let getSummaryOfDay = function(todo) {
    let meetleft =   todo.meetings + todo.meetdone
    console.log(meetleft)
}
addMeetings(myTodos,4)
addMeetings(myTodos,2)
meetDone(myTodos,5)
getSummaryOfDay(myTodos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code is as follows; there are typos in your code meet**D**one vs meet**d**one (small case)

```
let myTodos = {
    day:'monday',
    meetings: 0,
    meetdone: 0
}
let addMeetings = function(todo,meet=0) {
    todo.meetings = todo.meetings+meet;
}

let meetDone = function(todo,meet=0) {
    todo.meetdone = todo.meetdone-meet;
}
let restDay = function(todo) {
    todo.meetings=0;
    todo.meetDone=0;
}
let getSummaryOfDay = function(todo) {
    let meetleft = todo.meetings + todo.meetdone;
    console.log(meetleft);
}
addMeetings(myTodos,4);
addMeetings(myTodos,2);
meetDone(myTodos,5);
getSummaryOfDay(myTodos);
```

As a habit also I try to end the lines with a `;`, just a better way to write codes :) hope it helps